# What is meaning of high AIC value?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, model-selection, aic

I have a query related AIC value. I am getting very high AIC values while selecting multiple regression model, ranging from 4300-4600. Is it possible to get such high AIC values?

Answer (score 1):

Since the AIC scales linearly with the number of parameters it is easily possible to get a high AIC score. However, its absolute size is really not all that important.

Instead, the AIC is used mainly to select between different models where the lowest score is the most preferable. The difference in the AIC scores for two different models can be interpreted as 'extra information lost' by using the worse model in comparison to the better model.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). If you're interested in a score which has a cleaner interpretation you might also be interested in the [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion).